# Fastest way to add an element to a vector if it doesn't already exist in R

Tags: r, vector, unique

I am looking for the fastest way in R to add an element (of type character) to a vector if it doesn't already exist. Right now I have simply

```
vect=c("a","b","c")
vect=unique(c(vect,"b"))
vect=unique(c(vect,"d"))
```

etc

but I presume there must be better ways of doing this. Any thoughts?
(my vector has about 2 million strings (web URLs) )

cheers,
Tom

Comment: Any method that avoids growing `vect` will give you a speed improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%chin%` operator from `data.table` is specially written to be fast for character vectors. Here is an example:

```
#  Your data, and we would like to add elements from add
#  that are not already in vect
vect <- c("a","b","c")
add <- c( "a" , "d" , "e" , "b" )

#  Load package
require( data.table )

# %chin% operator is smae as %in% but fast and optimised for character sequences
c( vect , add[ ! add %chin% vect ] )
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: Splendid! Many thanks!! And in general - is there any preference in terms of speed of working either with vectors or lists? Are vectors indeed the fastest?

Comment: Welcome! A list *is* a vector. Try `is.vector( list( 1:10 ) )`. The difference is between whether the vector is recursive or atomic ( `is.recursive(  list( 1:10 ) )` vs. `is.atomic(  list( 1:10 ) )`. In general *i think* that working with atomic vectors using vectorised methods is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you want the union of two vectors:

```
vect <- c("a","b","c")
add <- c( "a" , "d" , "e" , "b" )

union(vect, add)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Which, as Simon points out, is the same as your solution.

Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(union(vect, add),c( vect , add[ ! add %chin% vect ] ),times=10)
# Unit: microseconds
#                           expr    min     lq  median     uq    max neval
#               union(vect, add) 12.628 13.243 13.3980 15.092 65.599    10
# c(vect, add[!add %chin% vect])  2.773  3.080  3.3885  4.620 51.740    10


vect <- as.character(seq_len(1e6))
microbenchmark(union(vect, add),c( vect , add[ ! add %chin% vect ] ),times=10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                          expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#              union(vect, add) 176.34441 188.82082 261.09802 339.96974 493.7810    10
#c(vect, add[!add %chin% vect])  35.37661  37.14743  47.06862  70.46896 203.7034    10
```

Comment: Which does exactly what the OP does... `unique(c(as.vector(x), as.vector(y)))`

Comment: Ha many thanks - so the chin solution is about 4-5 times faster than what I had with union - great! Thx for the benchmark!

Answer (score 0):

```
vect <- if (!"d" %in% vect) c(vect, "d") else vect
```